# Google Assistance integration with Android App

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, google-assistant-sdk

I want to integrate Google Assistant in my app. I am not just for launching the the app, also to operate on it like below:

App: Hi! What are you looking for?
User: T-shirts
App: What is the size?
User: 40
App: What is the color?
User: Any / Red and blue
App: Here is the T-shirts for you
User: Show order by Popularity 
App: Here it is.

Is it possible to do so by Google Assistance? Is it possible to start any activity of my app with proper intent extra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) as you will need to build a server side components to handle the voice/chat interaction. For an example of the voice interaction see: https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant

As to actually starting an app from Google Assistant. I don't believe there is a direct way.

<del>Alternatively that seems to be possible for a select set of voice commands through [Google Search Voice Actions](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/) to reach your app.</del>

<del>Note that Google isn't taking any more requests for custom Voice Actions:
https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions</del>

<del>And that the pages doesn't seem to have been updated since 2015 so I'm unclear what is still supported or not.</del>

From what I can tell the only part of Google Search Voice Actions that may be still around in 2017 is the ability to incorporate app data into Google Search via
[Firebase App Indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app)